# Pass object as a parameter to Oracle DB procedure in Express.js and oracledb

Tags: oracle, express, stored-procedures, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I'm trying to execute an SP in Express JS with "oracledb" dependency but when i try to pass the object doesn't work.

This is my type Object

```
create or replace TYPE ORDER_HEADER_OBJ AS object
(
  DOC_TYPE VARCHAR2(20),
  SALES_ORG NUMBER(10),
  DISTR_CHAN NUMBER(30),
  DIVISION NUMBER(10),
  REQ_DATE_H VARCHAR2(10),
  PO_METHOD VARCHAR2(30),
  REF_1 VARCHAR2(20),
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  INCOTERMS1 VARCHAR2(50),
  PMNTTRMS VARCHAR2(50),
  DLV_BLOCK VARCHAR2(50),
  COMPL_DLV VARCHAR2(50),
  PRICE_DATE VARCHAR2(50),
  CUST_GRP5 VARCHAR2(20),
  PURCH_NO_C VARCHAR2(30),
  REF_1_S VARCHAR2(20),
  DOC_DATE VARCHAR2(20),
  SHIP_COND NUMBER(10),
  COMP_CDE_B NUMBER(10),
  ALTTAX_CLS VARCHAR2(20),
  BILL_DATE VARCHAR2(10),
  CURRENCY VARCHAR2(5)
);
```

and i create a type table because i want to send 2 or more record

```
create or replace TYPE ORDER_HEADER_TAB AS TABLE OF ORDER_HEADER_OBJ;
```

And this is my SP:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_SaleOrders (order_header_in IN ORDER_HEADER_TAB)
AS
   mensaje_error VARCHAR2(200);
   filas_insertadas INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    BEGIN

        FOR i IN 1..order_header_in.COUNT LOOP
            INSERT INTO 
                TBLTESTHEADERWS (DOC_TYPE, SALES_ORG, DISTR_CHAN, DIVISION, REQ_DATE_H, 
                PO_METHOD, REF_1, NAME, INCOTERMS1,PMNTTRMS,
                DLV_BLOCK, COMPL_DLV, PRICE_DATE, CUST_GRP5, PURCH_NO_C, 
                REF_1_S, DOC_DATE, SHIP_COND, COMP_CDE_B, ALTTAX_CLS, 
                BILL_DATE, CURRENCY)
            VALUES 
                (order_header_in(i).DOC_TYPE, order_header_in(i).SALES_ORG, order_header_in(i).DISTR_CHAN, order_header_in(i).DIVISION, TO_DATE(order_header_in(i).REQ_DATE_H, 'YYYYMMDD'), 
                order_header_in(i).PO_METHOD, order_header_in(i).REF_1, order_header_in(i).NAME, order_header_in(i).INCOTERMS1, order_header_in(i).PMNTTRMS, 
                order_header_in(i).DLV_BLOCK, order_header_in(i).COMPL_DLV, TO_DATE(order_header_in(i).PRICE_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), order_header_in(i).CUST_GRP5, order_header_in(i).PURCH_NO_C, 
                order_header_in(i).REF_1_S, TO_DATE(order_header_in(i).DOC_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'),order_header_in(i).SHIP_COND, order_header_in(i).COMP_CDE_B, order_header_in(i).ALTTAX_CLS, 
                TO_DATE(order_header_in(i).BILL_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), order_header_in(i).CURRENCY);
        END LOOP;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
                mensaje_error := 'Error TBLTESTHEADERWS: Valor no válido para la columna';
            WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
                mensaje_error := 'Error TBLTESTHEADERWS: Valor no compatible con el tipo de datos de la columna';
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                mensaje_error := 'Error TBLTESTHEADERWS: Se ha producido un error desconocido al insertar los datos';
    END;

    IF filas_insertadas > 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ya se hizo el guiso.');
    ELSE
      -- Devuelve el mensaje de error al llamante
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mensaje_error);
    END IF;
END;
```

I tested my SP with this sentence and it works in DB:

```
DECLARE
order_header_table ORDER_HEADER_TAB := ORDER_HEADER_TAB();
BEGIN
order_header_table.EXTEND;
order_header_table(order_header_table.COUNT) := ORDER_HEADER_OBJ('value1', 'value2', ...);
order_header_table.EXTEND;
order_header_table(order_header_table.COUNT) := ORDER_HEADER_OBJ('value1', 'value2', ...);
SP_SaleOrderS(order_header_table);
END;
```

I do it like that the SP because i'm using Oracle 11G

Now i want to execute the SP in ExpressJs with oracledb and I get this error

"Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2"

this is my code:

```
const insertSalesOrderAllied = async (body) => {
  try {
    let data = [
      {
        DOC_TYPE: "API TEST",
        SALES_ORG: 10,
        DISTR_CHAN: 20,
        DIVISION: 30,
        REQ_DATE_H: "20220101",
        PO_METHOD: "method1",
        REF_1: "ref1",
        NAME: "name1",
        INCOTERMS1: "incoterms1",
        PMNTTRMS: "pmnttrms1",
        DLV_BLOCK: "dlv_block1",
        COMPL_DLV: "compl_dlv1",
        PRICE_DATE: "20220101",
        CUST_GRP5: "cust_grp5_1",
        PURCH_NO_C: "purch_no_c1",
        REF_1_S: "ref1_s1",
        DOC_DATE: "20220101",
        SHIP_COND: 1,
        COMP_CDE_B: 2,
        ALTTAX_CLS: "alttax_cls1",
        BILL_DATE: "20220101",
        CURRENCY: "USD",
      },
      {
        DOC_TYPE: "API TEST",
        SALES_ORG: 10,
        DISTR_CHAN: 20,
        DIVISION: 30,
        REQ_DATE_H: "20220101",
        PO_METHOD: "method1",
        REF_1: "ref1",
        NAME: "name1",
        INCOTERMS1: "incoterms1",
        PMNTTRMS: "pmnttrms1",
        DLV_BLOCK: "dlv_block1",
        COMPL_DLV: "compl_dlv1",
        PRICE_DATE: "20220101",
        CUST_GRP5: "cust_grp5_1",
        PURCH_NO_C: "purch_no_c1",
        REF_1_S: "ref1_s1",
        DOC_DATE: "20220101",
        SHIP_COND: 1,
        COMP_CDE_B: 2,
        ALTTAX_CLS: "alttax_cls1",
        BILL_DATE: "20220101",
        CURRENCY: "USD",
      },
    ];

    const result = await bd
      .open(
        `
        BEGIN
            SP_SaleOrders (:order_header_in );
        END;`,
        [data],
        true
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Error al ejecutar el SP SP_SaleOrder", err);
      });

    return {
      status: 201,
      message: result,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw boom.badRequest("Catch: " + error);
  }
};
```

What do i have to change to make it work?

I try changing the parameter to this:

```
const result = await bd
      .open(
        `
        BEGIN
            SP_SaleOrders (:order_header_in );
        END;`,
        {
          order_header_in: {
            type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_OBJECT,
            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
            val: data,
          },
        },
        true
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Error al ejecutar el SP SP_SaleOrder", err);
      });
```

But i get the error: "Error: DPI-1025: no object type specified for object variable"

I just want to execute the SP from ExpressJS using oracledb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the node-oracledb example [`selectobject.js`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/selectobject.js) and see the value(s) it uses for `type`.  See methods 3 & 4.  You need to specify the 'shape' of the object, and cannot use `oracledb.DB_TYPE_OBJECT`.

From `selectobject.js`:

```
    //
    // Insert Method 4: use the Oracle type name.
    // Note: use a fully qualified type name when possible.
    //

    await connection.execute(
      `INSERT INTO no_farmtab (id, farm) VALUES (:id, :f)`,
      { id: 4,
        f: {
          type: 'DBFARMTYPE',   // the name of the top level database type, case sensitive
          val: {                // a JavaScript object that maps to the DB object
            FARMERNAME: 'Boy',
            HARVEST: ['flowers', 'seedlings' ]
          }
        }
      }
    );
```

With 11.2 you might hit some object binding limitations that have been removed in more recent versions of Oracle Database.

Comment: Hi Cristopher! It Works your solution, thanks i really apreciate it!.

Comment: That's great. To clarify the comment about qualified names, repeated use of the type in the same connection will make efficient use of a type cache if you use USERNAME.TYPENAME e.g. `type: 'SCOTT.DBFARMTYPE'`.  This helps performance.

Comment: Hey Christopher! I have one more question if i add a parameter OUT SYS_REFCURSOR to return a result set when the SP ends, What do i have to add? I add one more parameter and it works but when i try to get the data i don't get nothing {
          asn_in: {
            type: "ASN_TAB",
            val: body,
          },
          p_cursor: {
            dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
            type: oracledb.CURSOR,
          },
        },

Comment: Check the documentation https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#ref-cursor-bind-parameters and the example https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/refcursor.js Open a new SO question with details if you still have a problem.

Comment: Thanks Christopheer! I made another question already becuase the problem persist and add more context with the changes on the SP and the code.